# A disc contains many random points. Each point is connected to its nearest neighbor. What is the expectation of average cluster size?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability, expectation, percolation

A disc contains $n$ independent uniformly distributed points. Each point is connected by a line segment to its nearest neighbor, forming clusters of connected points.

For example, here are $20$ random points and $7$ clusters, with an average cluster size of $\frac{20}{7}$.

[image]

> What is the expectation of the average cluster size, as $n\to\infty$ ?

I made a [random point generator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v4ziiyaonx?lang=zh-CN) that generates $20$ random points. The expectation of the average cluster size seems to be approximately $3$.

This question was [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4845153/398708) on Math SE. This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4845173/398708) provides useful context (but does not answer the question).

This question was inspired by the Math SE question [Stars in the universe - probability of mutual nearest neighbors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271497/stars-in-the-universe-probability-of-mutual-nearest-neighbors).

Comment: The points are on the disc, not on the circle.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I have changed it to disc.

Comment: The graph has no cycles, so the number of components is $n$ minus the number of edges, which is equal to the number of pairs which are mutually nearest neighbours. As $n\to\infty$, what you see locally around a typical point looks like a Poisson process. So the average number of clusters per point tends to $q_2/2$, where $q_2$ is the probability for a typical point in a 2-dimensional Poisson process to be in a mutually-nearest-neighbour pair. But isn't that already what's calculated by joriki in the "Stars in the universe" question you linked to?: $q_2/2\approx0.31075$. What am I missing...?

Comment: What graph is it that has no cycles?  If the points in the disk are all vertices of a fixed regular polygon, won't the nearest neighbor graph have a cycle (and only one component)?

Comment: @DanielAsimov The description doesn't specify what happens if there is a point with two equally near nearest neighbours. But anyway, if the points are uniformly distributed in continuous space, the probability of that happening is $0$.

Comment: @JamesMartin That seems right to me. I have written your comment as an answer.

Comment: @DanielAsimov Suppose no two points are exactly the same distance apart. Then we have a directed graph in which every vertex has outdegree one, so each connected component of the underlying undirected graph is unicyclic (the cycle might have just 1 or 2 vertices). In such a component, consider the pair of points that are closest together; they must form a cycle of length 2. But in the underlying undirected graph, a cycle of length 2 manifests itself as a single undirected edge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the comment by @James Martin answers my question.

The number of clusters equals the number of pairs of points that are mutually nearest neighbors. The probability that a point is in a mutually nearest neighbor pair is $p=\dfrac{1}{\frac43+\frac{\sqrt3}{2\pi}}\approx0.62150$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271604/398708)). So for $n$ points, the expected number of pairs that are mutually nearest neighbors approaches $\frac{np}{2}$. So the expected number of points per cluster approaches $\frac2p=\color{red}{\frac83+\frac{\sqrt3}{\pi}}\approx 3.218$.

Curiously, this is $(e+\frac12)\times0.99991...$ Is that just a coincidence?

(I may not be using terminology precisely enough; feel free to edit.)

Comment: Experimentally I keep getting values larger than $3.218$. Actually I never got anything below $3.22$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I could be wrong. What do your experiments suggest for the expectation?

Comment: Not sure, but certainly above $3.225$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე How many points are you using?

Comment: I took mean of 1000 attempts with 100 points, and  of 10 attempts with 1000 points, about 5 times each

Comment: I now started runs on 10000 points, but so far only got 3 attempts, mean is $3.22722$

Comment: Here is Mathematica code `f[M_, A_] := Mean[Table[With[{pts = Select[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {M, 2}], Norm[#] <= 1 &]}, N[Length[pts]/Length[ConnectedComponents[Graph[Table[p \[UndirectedEdge] First[SortBy[Complement[pts, {p}], EuclideanDistance[#, p] &]], {p, pts}]]]]]], {A}]]`

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძეI reckon it's just experimental error.

Comment: Maybe. Can you guess what could produce the upward bias?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't know, but I did trials with $4$ points and got $3.44$ (I guess that's the exact value for $n=4$).

Comment: Oh I see - you suggest that  the expectations decrease monotonously with $n$. This souns very convincing indeed.

Comment: With 100000 attempts, for $n=5,6,7,...$ I get $3.27, 3.43, 3.49, 3.505, 3.49, 3.475, 3.45, 3.42, ...$

Comment: How do you pick random points on the disk? ( i.e. be wary of Buffon'needle paradox).

Comment: @JérômeJEAN-CHARLES We use [disk point picking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html).

Comment: @Dan Perfect response (that teached me something). Thanks you.